# How do I write the jQuery in this code more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optimization

I have a basic todo list, with which I can click on the **li** element to toggle the **.completed** css class on and off. Besides when I click on the **X**, which is covered in a **span** inside the **li**, I can remove the **li**. Everything works fine, but my IDE told me I had a **duplicated jQuery selector**, which is **$("ul")**. How can I write this jQuery more efficiently?

```js
// check off specific todo by clicking
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

// click on X to delete todo
$("ul").on("click", "span", function (event) {
    // remove li
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    // prevent event from affecting parents element
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.completed {
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

#container {
  width: 100px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><span>X</span> Code</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Sleep</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Eat</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Run</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Jump</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: $("ul").on().on()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is use chaining:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
})
// click on X to delete todo
.on("click", "span", function (event) {
    // remove li
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    // prevent event from affecting parents element
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

The first call to `.on()` will return the jQuery object you constructed with the initial `$("ul")`. Thus, you can immediately make another call to `.on()`.

In this particular case, the redundant `$("ul")` probably isn't that big of a problem, but it's good to get into the habit of minimizing your DOM lookups.

Alternatively, you can always just stash the jQuery object in a variable:

```
var $ul = $("ul");

// check off specific todo by clicking
$ul.on("click", "li", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

// click on X to delete todo
$ul.on("click", "span", function (event) {
    // remove li
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    // prevent event from affecting parents element
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can chain the methods together or store a reference to the selector object:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
}).on("click", "span", function (event) {
    // remove li
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    // prevent event from affecting parents element
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Or

```
var $ul = $("ul");

$ul.on("click", "li", function () {
     $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

$ul.on("click", "span", function (event) {
    // remove li
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    // prevent event from affecting parents element
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do chaining. jQuery is design to be used like that.

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
}).on("click", "span", function (event) {
    // remove li
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    // prevent event from affecting parents element
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```